# rosemacs error : dynamic-completion-table

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After installing ros-noetic on a debian 10. I installed ros-noetic-rosemacs via apt. The installed version is : 0.4.17-1buster.20220221.094135.

When I run emacs (emacs --debug-init) I get the following error:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function dynamic-completion-table)
  (dynamic-completion-table #'(lambda (str) (rosemacs-bsearch str ros-all-topics)))
  (setq topic-completor (dynamic-completion-table #'(lambda (str) (rosemacs-bsearch str ros-all-topics))))
  load-with-code-conversion("/opt/ros/noetic/share/emacs/site-lisp/rosemacs.el" "/opt/ros/noetic/share/emacs/site-lisp/rosemacs.el" nil t)
  require(rosemacs)
  load-with-code-conversion("/opt/ros/noetic/share/emacs/site-lisp/rosemacs-con..." "/opt/ros/noetic/share/emacs/site-lisp/rosemacs-con..." nil t)
  require(rosemacs-config)
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/hdd/.emacs.d/init.el" "/home/hdd/.emacs.d/init.el" t t)
  load("/home/hdd/.emacs.d/init" noerror nomessage)
  startup--load-user-init-file(#f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x10b2151e256b0ed8>) #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode -0x1f3c686ddc0cdc35>) t)
  command-line()
  normal-top-level()
```

Do you have any idea how to make rosemacs work?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/416843/rosemacs-error-:-dynamic-completion-table/) by [hdd--robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/155797/hdd--robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2023-06-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems that the problem is that the function "dynamic-completion-table" has changed its name in emacs, now it is called "completion-table-dynamic".

To solve the problem, I changed in the file: "/opt/ros/noetic/share/emacs/site-lisp/rosemacs.el" all occurrences of "dynamic-completion-table" by "completion-table- dynamic".
it seems to work for now.

---

Originally posted by [hdd--robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/155797/hdd--robot/) with karma: 38 on 2023-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2023-06-29**:
Glad you found a workaround. Seeing `/opt/ros/noetic/share/emacs` in your error output, I guess your `rosemacs` is installed via the installer, of which code is maintained at https://github.com/code-iai/ros_emacs_utils/issues. Why don't you submit a bugfix?